# mod_rewrite in subdirectory to subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having trouble getting my mod_rewrite to work. In a frustrating fashion it works in my dev mode and at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ it works just fine.

I have made sure mod_rewrite is enabled on my server.

What I am trying to do is have the following URL

```
a. http://www.site.net/chat/
b. http://www.site.net/chat/groups.php?test
```

Invisibly redirect to

```
a. http://www.site.net/chat/www/page_loader.php/
b. http://www.site.net/chat/www/page_loader.php/groups.php?test
```

The www subdirectory contains all the files for chat. The .htaccess is contained within the chat subfolder though having a quick test whiles typing this question, it seems to behave differently when I place it in the root directory (though not work there either). The .htacess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#place everything in the www directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^.*/chat/www/.*$
RewriteRule ^.*chat/(.*)$ chat/www/$1

#send everything through the page loader
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpg|png|swf|css|html|js|ico|pdf)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/chat/www/page_loader.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/chat/www/page_loader.php/
RewriteRule ^.*chat/www/(.*)$ chat/www/page_loader.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

When I run the code on the htaccess tester (link above) using the following URL

```
http://www.site.net/chat/groups.php?test
```

The result is exactly as I want it to be:

```
http://www.site.net/chat/www/page_loader.php/groups.php?test
```

The page loader is just a script which I automatically run to include common definitions etc. before loading the required script. It is a system I brought over from another site I work on.

Even if I take everything to do with the pageloader out the first section does not even append the /www/ as required.

I am at a loss here. How can I get the desired result? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Place this in `/chat/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /chat/

RewriteRule ^/?$ www/page_loader.php/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|swf|css|html|js|ico|pdf)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!www/page_loader\.php).+)$ www/page_loader.php/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you for the response anubhava. This doesn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: What URL did you use to test it and what is location of your .htaccess?

Comment: I placed the htaccess within the chat subfolder (/chat/.htacess) which is 1 level down from root. I then used the url http://www.site.net/chat/ to test it. It turned up the same results as before.